# C# and delegates on graph traversing : how to improve reuse of code

Tags: c#, oop, graph, delegates

I'm working on a graph implementation.
My Graph class looks like this:

```
public class Graph<VERTEX_TYPE, EDGE_TYPE, IDENTIFIER_TYPE> 
    where VERTEX_TYPE : Identifier<IDENTIFIER_TYPE>
    where EDGE_TYPE : Identifier<IDENTIFIER_TYPE>
    where IDENTIFIER_TYPE : IConvertible
{
...
}
```

(Please don't care about the implemented interface, they're not relevant for the question).

Both Vertex and Edge class contains some generic data that can be accessed this way:

```
public class Vertex<VERTEX_TYPE,EDGE_TYPE,IDENTIFIER_TYPE>  
    where VERTEX_TYPE : Identifier<IDENTIFIER_TYPE>
    where EDGE_TYPE : Identifier<IDENTIFIER_TYPE>
{
    public VERTEX_TYPE Data{get;private set;}
    ....
}

public class Edge<EDGE_TYPE,VERTEX_TYPE,IDENTIFIER_TYPE> 
    where EDGE_TYPE : Identifier<IDENTIFIER_TYPE>
    where VERTEX_TYPE : Identifier<IDENTIFIER_TYPE>
{

    public EDGE_TYPE Data{get;private set;}
    ....
}
```

Now I have a GraphVisitor class that implements some algorithms. When the Graph is traversed I want some delegates to be called on both edges and vertices that are currently been traversed by the algorithm.

I defined 2 pair of delegates, one pair is related to operations that have to be performed on the graph elements, such as `Vertex<VERTEX_TYPE,EDGE_TYPE,IDENTIFIER_TYPE>` .
The second pair of delegates is related to operations that have be performed only on data holded.

```
public class GraphVisitor<VERTEX_TYPE, EDGE_TYPE, IDENTIFIER_TYPE> 
    where VERTEX_TYPE : Identifier<IDENTIFIER_TYPE>
    where EDGE_TYPE : Identifier<IDENTIFIER_TYPE>
    where IDENTIFIER_TYPE : IConvertible

{
    public delegate void VertexDataOperation(VERTEX_TYPE vertex);
    public delegate void EdgeDataOperation(EDGE_TYPE vertex);
    public delegate void VertexOperation(Vertex<VERTEX_TYPE,EDGE_TYPE,IDENTIFIER_TYPE> vertex);
    public delegate void EdgeOperation(Edge<EDGE_TYPE,VERTEX_TYPE,IDENTIFIER_TYPE> vertex);
       .....
}
```

I have implemented the BFS algorithm (I avoid to post the whole implementation), taking two delegates as parameters:

```
public void BFS(VertexOperation op, EdgeOperation edgeOp)
{
...      
Vertex<VERTEX_TYPE,EDGE_TYPE,IDENTIFIER_TYPE> currentVertex;
op(currentVertex);

foreach (Edge<EDGE_TYPE,VERTEX_TYPE,IDENTIFIER_TYPE> e in currentVertex.NeighBors())
{
    edgeOp(e);
    ...
}
...
```

I was attemping to write a BFS version for `VertexDataOperation` and `EdgeDataOperation`, when I realized that I eventually should copy all my BFS code in order to use the 2 different delegates parameter type:

```
public void BFS(VertexDataOperation op, EdgeDataOperation edgeOp)
...
Vertex<VERTEX_TYPE,EDGE_TYPE,IDENTIFIER_TYPE> currentVertex;
op(currentVertex.Data); //method differs only here

foreach (Edge<EDGE_TYPE,VERTEX_TYPE,IDENTIFIER_TYPE> e in currentVertex.NeighBors())
{
    edgeOp(e.Data);//method differs only here
    ...
}
```

I would like to avoid having identical implementation of the same method. The only things change are method signature and the object on which the method is called.

Does anyone have any idea in order to improve the design of this code?

EDIT:

I could pass all 4 delegates to a function but I'd only use single couple of them during each traversal, so It doesn't look very clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd strongly advise you to change your naming for type parameters. The convention is to use a `T` prefix and then a PascalCased name, e.g. `TVertex` and `TEdge`.

Next, if you find yourself wanting several related delegates, that sounds like you really want an interface with several methods. You can always create a no-op implementation of the interface to allow just one method to be overridden - or even provide static methods which create an instance of a concrete implementation from a delegate, if you want to use lambda expressions to express actions.

This is basically what Reactive Extensions does with the [`IObserver<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx) interface, and it works very well.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Actually I'm exactly using no-op implementation. I hope the compiler will optimize such no-op method call, does it?

Comment: @Heisenbug: No, the compiler can't optimize it, as it's a call to a virtual method. But why do you care? Do you have any evidence that this is a bottleneck?

Comment: no , actually no evidence. I just care because I'm planning of apply several graph traversing algorithms on quite huge graphs, so I was trying to avoid unuseful method calls.

Comment: @Heisenbug: Sounds like you need to do some performance analysis then - but don't micro-optimize away from an elegant solution before you have evidence that it's a problem :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. And thanks for C# in depth too. I'm reading it and I begin to love C# ;)